# How get last 10 tweets of certain user using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I need to receive just few my last tweets for short timeline on my homepage. Tell me the easiest way to do this.
PS I use Codeigniter and it would be nice to get a solution for it ^_^

Thank you so much for the earlier

Comment: You might like to see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422879/best-twitter-php-library

Comment: Have you looked at the Twitter API's? Why not have a go first and if you can't make this work post what you tried then ask some questions. What you're asking is for the community to write your code with not much apparent effort from your side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zend_Service_Twitter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html) example from the manual:

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
    'username' => 'johndoe',
    'accessToken' => $token,
    'count' => 10,
));
$response   = $twitter->status->userTimeline();
```

You can use it just fine with codeignitor.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking into this same thing this morning. Found this helpful tidbit from Greg Aker http://www.gregaker.net/2011/feb/12/codeigniter_reactors_caching_drivers/ It loads in the latest X number of tweets as well as uses caching. There is a bunch more query params that can be sent t the Twitter API. You can see them all at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation