# Get tweets from specific user with Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to get tweets from a specific user but can't find a way to do this from within Code Igniter. I saw several pages looking for solutions like:

- [How get last 10 tweets of certain user using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743857/how-get-last-10-tweets-of-certain-user-using-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422879/best-twitter-php-library
- http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html
- https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION

But all of them seems to be for authorization and not for get tweets. Any help or advice on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library on github :

[TwitterFetecher for codeigniter](https://github.com/joeauty/TwitterFetcher-CodeIgniter-Spark) and Read the documenation

Place `TwitterFetcher.php` on **libraries** folder .

on your controller /action load it

```
public function home() {
$this->load->library('twitterfetcher');

        $tweets = $this->twitterfetcher->getTweets(array(
            'consumerKey'       => 'yourkey',
            'consumerSecret'    => 'yourkey',
            'accessToken'       => 'yourkey',
            'accessTokenSecret' => 'yourkey',
            'usecache'          => true,
            'count'             => 2,  //this how many tweets to fectch
            'numdays'           => 30
        ));
    $data['twiites'] = $tweets  ; 
  $this->load->view('home/home',$data);
 }
```

**CHAW!**

Comment: I can't figure where we pass the username for this library. Can you please explain how can I do this?

Comment: @Yasmeen you need to login to your twitter account and developer api then generate the keys..above `yourkeys` are like username

Comment: Yes, so I can't get latest tweets from another account with this library?. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: it shoud have been your API developer setting ...am sure it will work put your twitter.php on libraries folder ..

Comment: must this be on a live server or a local one can work just fine? @danielad

Comment: this works in live as well as on test server with ias long as internet connection :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [CI Sparks](http://getsparks.org/)? The [example build](http://getsparks.org/make-sparks) Spark does similar to what you are asking

There are a couple of packages there that look like they will do what you want.

E.g

- [Twitter](http://getsparks.org/packages/twitter/versions/HEAD/show)
- [mmtwitterfetcher](http://getsparks.org/packages/mmtwitterfetcher/versions/HEAD/show)